# Protecting microcontroller from inputs rising faster than Vcc

Tags: arduino, adc

I have a microcontroller (ATMEGA328) that I'm using to do analog data acquisition. The problem is that I want my ADC values to be referenced to a regulated external source that is ~3V, but that source rises faster than my power supply. Since the microcontroller has ESD protection diodes like shown, I think it is likely to blow up when the circuit starts. Is that true? If so, how can I create a low impedance path (<32 Ohm) between ARef and the external source, but still protect the circuit?

The external source is part of an irreplaceable system, so I don't want to just put a Schottky to VCC since that might overdraw the external regulator.

I thought perhaps an n-channel MOSFET with the gate attached to VCC between the pin and the reference?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flRGgB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your VREF voltage source.

If you have an enable, then I would tie the enable to the 5V source, so that it is only enabled when the 5V source is higher than 3V. You can do this using a voltage divider, kind of like an [undervoltage lockout](http://www.tij.co.jp/ods/images/SNVSA79/UVLO_cir_lvsbg1.gif) configuration.

If you don't have an enable, then you can still do undervoltage lockout, or you can just have the 5V supply enhance a MOSFET.

Another possibility, if your 5V supply has a "power good" output, is to tie the power good to the enable of the 3V supply.

Comment: I don't have enable lines, but I imagine similar applications would. Glad to hear I'm not crazy on the MOSFET idea.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that Vref is not changing much you can put a grounded capacitor (e.g. 100nF) at the Vref input and connect it via a current limiting resistor (e.g. 10k\$\Omega\$) to the external Vref. The capacitor gives you low impedance. The resistor limits the current in case that Vref > Vcc.

If for some reason that is not an option you can insert a unity gain OpAmp that has a high impedance input and a low impedance output.

Comment: The first solution works well for input pins, but the AREF pin has the shown 32k resistor, which would form a divider with the 10k, so not so good.

Comment: @Paul Foster: You didn't specify the range of the analog voltage at the input of the ADC. If its upper limit is below Vref = 3V * 32k / (10K + 32k) = 2.28V then there is no problem having a voltage divider.